# Добавления регулярных выражений в конструктор

Tags: android, регулярные-выражения, kotlin

Пробую изменить значения аргументов в конструкторе с помощью регулярных выражений следующим образом:

```java
constructor(message: String = "", classError: String = ERROR_CLASS_API_RESPONSE) : this() {
    this.message = message.replace("""^[^@]*""".toRegex())
    this.classError = classError.replace("""^[^@]*""".toRegex())
}
```

Но ругается на типы аргументов метода replace. Не совсем пойму что ещё нужно добавить?

Comment: Во-первых `replace()` требует 2 аргументов https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence) . Во-вторых `toRegex()` возвращает не строку https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-regex.html

Comment: Ну вот у меня и проблема, не очень смекаю что добавить в качестве второго аргумента. А по поводу toRegex() ну так всё верно он преобразует строку, то что мне надо.

Comment: В документации же написано, что значат оба аргумента. А `toRegex()` возвращает НЕ строку, а Вы эту НЕ строку пытаетесь кинуть в `replace()`, который принимает ДВЕ СТРОКИ. Я уж не знаю, как понятней объяснить.

Comment: Метод public inline fun CharSequence.replace(regex: Regex, replacement: String): String = regex.replace(this, replacement)
где вы видите здесь ДВЕ строки? по-моему здесь только 1.

Comment: Ааа, так это котлиновские экстеншены. Ну тогда Вам остается только добавить второй аргумент-строку, на которую Вы заменяете то, что соответствует в исходной строке указанному регулярному выражению.

Comment: Так java или kotlin?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на `.replace("""^[^@]+""".toRegex(), "")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, пришёл к этому из комментариев выше. Спасибо, только regex всё таки не правильно составил) Может подскажете как его огричить пробелом в конце? ну то есть не все символы после @ заменять на пустую строку, а все символы которые до пробела находятся. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Пример приведите. `^[^@]+` найдет 1+ символов, отличных от `@`, от начала строки.

Comment: ну у автора в конце звездочка, значит найдёт все символы которые находятся после @

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ну то есть если у меня сообщение someerror@make additiolity, то на данный момент преобразует сообщение к someerror, а надо к someerror additiolity .

Comment: Т.е. удалить всё от `@` до ближайшего пробела? [`.replace("""@\S+""".toRegex(), "")`](https://regex101.com/r/JbaQLY/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew а разве \S это пробел? а не наоборот? Ну то есть \\s вроде как пробельный символ.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew вроде как тесты прошли) спасибо большое)

Comment: @Morozov: `\s` - это класс пробельных символов, но удалить надо только те, что не являются ими после `@`. Поэтому нужно использовать `\S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Котлине [метод `replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html)  требует как минимум два аргумента: регулярное выражение и строка замены.

Для того, чтобы удалить всё от `@` до ближайшего пробела, используйте

```
.replace("""@\S+""".toRegex(), "")
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/JbaQLY/1).

**Подробности**:

- `@` - символ `@`
- `\S+` - 1 и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов.